# What does double "at" (@) marks mean in this SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I couldn't find anything about this in MySQL documentation.

```
SELECT accesion_id, 
       definition 
  FROM accesion_table 
 WHERE search_word @@ ? OFFSET ? LIMIT Const.MAX_DISP_COUNT;
```

Comment: Sounds framework-specific. Which one is being used?

Comment: The only SQL I know that uses `@@` is T-SQL, used in SQL Server and Informix but there's no text immediate afterwards for an actual command (IE: `@@ROWCOUNT`).  The `?` looks like a MySQL Prepared Statement is being used; that's a placeholder for a bind variable.  But the OFFSET is in the wrong spot - it should come after LIMIT, not before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Oracle the '@@' to point to the current directory of the executing file. Could it be that MySql might be following Oracles lead?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the code that is executing this sql statement has some parser that's handling this odd syntax, since the the @@, ? and Const.MAX_DISPLAY_COUNT aren't part of MySQL. Also the keyword OFFSET must be placed after the LIMIT keyword.

Comment: I am sorry, this is postgre sql